# Bypassing captcha with Python

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, tesseract, captcha

I'm using Tesseract, PIL and ImageMagick Tools for bypassing a captcha.

Here's the code:

```
import pytesseract
import sys
import argparse
try:
    import Image
except ImportError:
    from PIL import Image
from subprocess import check_output


def resolve(path):
    print("Resampling the Image")
    check_output(['convert', path, '-resample', '600', path])
    return pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(path))

argparser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
argparser.add_argument('/Users/rodrigopeniche/Documents/workspace/WebScraping/captcha.png',help = 'Captcha file path')
args = argparser.parse_args()
path = args.path
print('Resolving Captcha')
captcha_text = resolve(path)
print('Extracted Text', captcha_text)
```

Firstly, is there anyway to execute this code without having to pass the file location when executing in the command line?

And then I get this error when executing:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/rodrigopeniche/Documents/workspace/WebScraping/captchabypasser.py", line 20, in <module>
path = args.path
AttributeError: 'Namespace' object has no attribute 'path'
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you never define an argument called `path`. Change the add_argument line to:

```
argparser.add_argument('path', help='Captcha file path')

#Or, if you want to make the command line parameter optional, give it a default

argparser.add_argument('path', default='/Users/rodrigopeniche/Documents/workspace/WebScraping/captcha.png', help='Captcha file path')
```

Of course, if you have no interest in parsing command line arguments, you can just set the path manually.